# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0 | .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
Public Class VendorMain
Dim conn As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim strcon As String = "Data Source=C1DSC-PC1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vendor;Integrated Security=True"

Private Sub loaddata()
    conn = New SqlConnection(strcon)
    conn.Open()
    Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM vendortable"
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(str, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "vendortable")
    dgVendor.DataSource = ds.Tables("vendortable")
    da.Dispose()
    conn.Close()

End Sub
Private Sub loadnewdata()
    conn = New SqlConnection(strcon)
    conn.Open()
    Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM vendortable"
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(str, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "vendortable")
    dgVendor.DataSource = ds.Tables("vendortable")
    da.Dispose()
    conn.Close()

End Sub
Private Sub LoadCombo()

    conn.Open()
    strcon = "select * from PAS"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(strcon, conn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If dr.HasRows Then
        While dr.Read()
            mcPAS.Items.Add(dr("Products and Services"))
            mcUpdatePAS.Items.Add(dr("Products and Services"))
        End While

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub VendorMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    conn = New SqlConnection(strcon)
    conn.Open()
    loaddata()
    LoadCombo()
    loaditems()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub


Private Sub dgVendor_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgVendor.CellDoubleClick
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow
        row = Me.dgVendor.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        View.txtVendorID.Text = row.Cells("VendorID").Value.ToString
        View.txtSupplier.Text = row.Cells("Suppliers/Vendors").Value.ToString
        View.txtPAS.Text = row.Cells("Products and Services").Value.ToString
        View.txtAddress.Text = row.Cells("Address").Value.ToString
        View.txtFax.Text = row.Cells("Fax Number").Value.ToString
        View.txtOffice.Text = row.Cells("Office Number").Value.ToString
        View.txtContact.Text = row.Cells("Contact Person").Value.ToString
        View.txtOther.Text = row.Cells("Other Info/Details").Value.ToString
    End If
    View.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub loaditems()
    Dim con As New SqlConnection()
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C1DSC-PC1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vendor;Integrated Security=True"
    con.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from PAS", con)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    da.Fill(table)
    mcAddPAS.DataSource = New BindingSource(table, Nothing)
    mcAddPAS.DisplayMember = "Products and Services"
    mcPAS.DataSource = New BindingSource(table, Nothing)
    mcPAS.DisplayMember = "Products and Services"
    mcUpdatePAS.DataSource = New BindingSource(table, Nothing)
    mcUpdatePAS.DisplayMember = "Products and Services"
    'write the column name which will be diplayed
    'you can even use  valueMember property, 
    'Names - DisplayMember - this is was you see in comboBox
    'IDs - ValueMember can be used as additional value of Person
    'column name for value
    conn.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub btnAddItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddItem.Click
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim constr As String = "Data Source=C1DSC-PC1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vendor;Integrated Security=True"

    Try
        con.ConnectionString = constr
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into PAS ([Products and Services]) values(@products)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@products", txtAddPAS.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Item Inserted!", "Confirmed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        loaditems()
        con.Dispose()
        con.Close()
        txtAddPAS.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnDeleteItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteItem.Click
    Dim cummand As New SqlCommand
    Dim cunnection As New SqlConnection
    Dim constrng As String = "Data Source=C1DSC-PC1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vendor;Integrated Security=True"
    Try
        cunnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C1DSC-PC1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vendor;Integrated Security=True"
        cunnection.Open()
        cummand.Connection = cunnection
        cummand.CommandText = "Delete From PAS where PASID=@pasID"
        cummand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@pasID", lblItemID.Text))
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Item Deleted!", "Confirmed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        cummand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        loaditems()
        txtAddPAS.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally
        cunnection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub mcAddPAS_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mcAddPAS.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    connetionString = "Data Source=C1DSC-PC1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vendor;Integrated Security=True"
    connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PASID from PAS where [Products and Services]='" & mcAddPAS.Text & "'", connection)
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        connection.Close()
        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            lblItemID.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("PASID").ToString()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub MetroButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MetroButton1.Click
    'View.lblItemID.Text = View.dgItems.Item("ItemID", View.dgItems.CurrentRow.Index).Value()
    View.txtVendorID.Text = dgVendor.Item("VendorID", dgVendor.CurrentRow.Index).Value()
    View.txtSupplier.Text = dgVendor.Item("Suppliers/Vendors", dgVendor.CurrentRow.Index).Value()
    View.txtPAS.Text = dgVendor.Item("Products and Services", dgVendor.CurrentRow.Index).Value()
    View.txtAddress.Text = dgVendor.Item("Address", dgVendor.CurrentRow.Index).Value()
    View.txtFax.Text = dgVendor.Item("Fax Number", dgVendor.CurrentRow.Index).Value()
    View.txtOffice.Text = dgVendor.Item("Office Number", dgVendor.CurrentRow.Index).Value()
    View.txtContact.Text = dgVendor.Item("Contact Person", dgVendor.CurrentRow.Index).Value()
    View.txtOther.Text = dgVendor.Item("Other Info/Details", dgVendor.CurrentRow.Index).Value()
    View.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    lbldatetime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim komand As New SqlCommand
    Dim connect As New SqlConnection("Data Source=C1DSC-PC1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vendor;Integrated Security=True")
    Try
        connect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C1DSC-PC1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vendor;Integrated Security=True"
        connect.Open()
        komand.Connection = connect
        komand.CommandText = "Insert into vendortable ([Suppliers/Vendors],[Products and Services],Address,[Fax Number],[Office Number],[Contact Person],[Other Info/Details]) values(@suppliers,@pas,@address,@fax,@office,@contact,@other)"
        komand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suppliers", txtAddVendor.Text)
        komand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pas", mcPAS.Text)
        komand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddAddress.Text)
        komand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", txtAddFax.Text)
        komand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@office", txtAddOffice.Text)
        komand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", txtAddContact.Text)
        komand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@other", txtAddOther.Text)
        komand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Record Inserted!", "Confirmed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        loaddata()
        connect.Dispose()
        connect.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

This is my code. Why do I keep receiving this error. Does my connectionstring have the correct format??
I am working with this system with 3 INSERT statements. One for the inserting 1st table, 2nd for 2nd table and 3rd table. I always use this way to insert data to Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Comment: "Does my connectionstring have the correct format??" - how would we *know*? All we know is that you assign it from a variable called `strcon`, that doesn't appear anywhere else in your code sample.

Comment: I putted the strcon in the public class form

Comment: That doesn't help **us** to answer **your** question when the problem appears to be with the connection string and *we* can't *see it*.

Comment: Here is my code in the public class form

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question and add the code. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: okay sorry I'm just new here in stack. okay I'll edit it now my full code

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've already posted the full code

Comment: When I inserted a  record, it inserted successfully but the error comes out after.

Comment: the error I'm receiving is at btnAdd

Comment: I suggest you to simplify your code. The connectionstring is a constant and should be stored in the app.config file (or web.config) under the section _ConnectionStrings_ [See here how to do it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx) after that, remove all your strings that replicate the same constant with the simple call ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["name of your connection"].ConnectionString. In this way you will have just one point to check for the correctness of your connection.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Please see [ask].

Comment: Finally, you are really trying to shoot your feets. Do not use these global variables. If you just forget one time to call New on them before using them you are toasted. Just use local variables declaring and initializing them anytime you need them

Answer (score 0):

first of all, can you put line break from the start of your program, so that we could locate the error happens. then feed it back to us.

thank you